# Recursive addition/subtraction in python with negative integers

Tags: python, recursion, negative-number

I am trying to make a program that adds and subtracts two arguments using recursion. So far my program is working for positive integers but I am completely lost about how I can make this work for negative integers. I would really appreciate your help.

Here is my code so far:

```
def add(x,y):
    """add takes x and y and adds them together"""
    if y == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return add1(add(x, sub1(y)))

def sub(x,y):
    """sub takes x and y and subtracts them"""
    if y == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return sub1(sub(x, sub1(y)))
def add1(x):
   return x+1

def sub1(x):
   return x-1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with this

```
def add(x,y):
    if y > 0:
        return add(x, y-1) + 1
    elif y < 0:
        return add(x, y+1) - 1
    else:
        return x
```

Subtract would be the same idea, but flip the signs

```
def sub(x,y):
    if y > 0:
        return sub(x, y-1) - 1
    elif y < 0:
        return sub(x, y+1) + 1
    else:
        return x
```

Testing

```
>>> add(3,5)
8
>>> add(3,0)
3
>>> add(3,-5)
-2    
>>> subtract(8,3)
5
>>> subtract(3,8)
-5
>>> subtract(3,0)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

In each case you try to get y closer to 0 since y==0 is the base case for your recursion.

- If y is positive, you do so by repeatedly subtracting 1.
- If y is negative, you repeatedly add 1.

In every case, do "the right thing" to x:

**Addition**

1. if x or y is 0, return the other value
2. if y is positive, add 1 to x, subtract 1 from y: 6 + 2 = 7 + 1 = 8 + 0 = 8
3. if y is negative, subtract 1 from x, add 1 to y: 6 + (-2) = 5 + (-1) = 4 + 0 = 4

code:

```
def add(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    elif x == 0:
        return y
    elif y > 0:
        return add(add1(x), sub1(y))
    else:
        return add(sub1(x), add1(y))
```

**Subtraction**

1. if y is 0, return x
2. if y is positive, subtract 1 from x, subtract 1 from y: 6 - 2 = 5 - 1 = 4 - 0 = 4
3. if y is negative, add 1 to x, add 1 to y: 6 - (-2) = 7 - (-1) = 8 - 0 = 8

code:

```
def sub(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    elif y > 0:
        return sub(sub1(x), sub1(y))
    else:
        return sub(add1(x), add1(y))
```